# Ruby on Rails - Check if object has been changed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, model

In my application I have models `Post` & `Image`. Both `Post` & `Image` have same columns: `description`, `title`, `tags`.

*This is what I have in my models:*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, inverse_of: :post
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
```

I use `nested_forms` when a user is creating a post so they can add as many images they want under a post.

Currently when a user is creating a *post*, that post's **description**, **title** & **tags** will be added to its `images` *(this is because of some stuff I do for users)* from `Post` model.

*This is how I am doing it.*

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :adding_details_to_images

private

  def adding_details_to_images
      self.images.each { |image| image.update_attributes(
          description: self.description,
          title: self.title,
          tags: self.tags
        )
      }
  end
```

Users still can go to `images#edit` view and change **description**, **title** & **tags** individually for each image.

How can I see if each image's **description**, **title** & **tags** has been manually overwritten/updated or they still use/inherit post's **description**, **title** & **tags**?

Is it good idea/practice to make a array from *Post's*, **description**, **title** & **tags** & *Image's*, **description**, **title** & **tags** and check if they match? If so how can make as a function so I can call from model or controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a variation of [gabrielhilal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688371/ruby-on-rails-check-if-object-has-been-changed/44688967#44688967):

> Is it good idea/practice to make a array from Post's, description,
>   title & tags & Image's, description, title & tags and check if they
>   match?

Yes, you could do it like this:

image.rb

```
def same_as_post?
  summary == post.summary
end

def summary
  [description, title, tags]
end
```

post.rb

```
def summary
  [description, title, tags]
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Gerry. Checking `updated_at` wouldn't work since `images` has other columns then `description`, `title` & `tags` and if they changed other columns, `updated_at` would be changed anyway. You think if making a array and compare them to each other is not a good idea, or there is a better way? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @user6589814 Then i woulg go with gabrielhilal answer, I think it is what your are looking for.

Comment: Works great man :) Thanks a bunch and thanks for you taking time on this :)

Comment: @FriendofAfriend Glad to help! Since this answer was a result of a shared effort, it would be nice to accept one answer and upvote the other.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry, I've already done that. Alway thumbs up for anyone who take their time to help out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure it was manually updated or not, I would store this information in the `images` table (i.e a `data_from_post` boolean field) and then make sure you set it correctly in both cases (callback and update endpoint).

However if you just want to know if the details are the same (user might update these fields with the same data as associated post), you could add something like the following to `Image` model:

```
def same_as_post?
  description == post.description && title == post.title && tags == post.tags
end
```

Comment: Thanks @gabrielhilal. Would `same_as_post?` got to `Image` model or `Post`. Yes I just want to know if they are the same. You think if making a array from both tables details and compare them to each other is not a good idea? Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @user6589814 Yes, you could create a method in each model that creates an array with the three columns and compare them.